# Mapping Similarities based on Attributes

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
Bob 123.com random.com something.something.com etc
Mike 123.com random.com something.something.something.com etc
Joe etc.com random.domain.com random.com something.com
```

The names are the labels I am using and the domain names are the attributes that I would want to connect to one another based on similarity (name of attribute). How can I do this without typing every single one of the labels and attributes?

Comment: 1. You want every "name" ("Bob", "Mike", "Joe", etc.) to be a node label? It would be better to have a single node label, say "Person", and each `Person` node can have a "name" property (that should probably be indexed or have a uniqueness constraint). 2. Can you clarify what you are trying to do with the domain names?

Comment: Hmm, that could work. I just want to basically show every single person thats associated with each domainname in a visual format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your CSV file format, here is an example of how to create unique `Person` and `Domain` nodes, and the relationships between them:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'url-of-csv' AS row
MERGE (p:Person {name: row[0]})
WITH p, TAIL(row) AS domains
UNWIND domains AS domain
MERGE (d:Domain {name: domain})
MERGE (p)-[:IN]->(d);
```

And there is an example of how you'd get all the people who are in the `random.com` domain:

```
MATCH (d:Domain {name: 'random.com'})<-[:IN]-(p:Person)
RETURN p;
```